# IPv4Network object as key in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, dictionary

I'm using an `IPv4Network` from the `ipaddress` module as keys in a dict. This allows me to look for duplication quickly, and note some other data.

However, I'm curious if I can stack the IN statements and keep away from O(n) processing.

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Network
net1 = IPv4Network('10.10.10.0/24')
net2 = IPv4Network('10.10.10.128/25')
net3 = IPv4Network('10.10.10.0/24')

dict1 = {net1: 'Winner!'}
print(dict1.get(net3))
Winner!

if net3 in dict1:
    print('Yup')
Yup

# -------- This doesn't work, looking for way to accomplish it.
if net2.network_address in dict1:
    print('Wouldn't that be nice?)
# --- Yes I can do this.
for keys in dict1:
    if net2.network_address in keys:
         print(keys, 'I\'m inside you!')
```

Any ideas for a clever trick? A way to restructure this to leverage some built-in?

I want to know if

1. The key exists in duplicate (easy); and
2. If the `IPv4Network` is contained inside as one of the keys.

Comment: I've made a few edits on the post to correct some typos and improve overall readability. In question #2, I assumed you meant `IPv4Network` when you referred to `"network"`, so I changed it there. Feel free to roll back that particular change if you think I got it wrong.

Comment: I'm tired, and was trying to fix several things and you beat me to the punch. I was literally editing when it told me you updated it. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to do what you want. Python's dictionary lookups use hashing to efficiently find exact matches for the dictionary's keys. There's no way for the hash of a network to match all the addresses it contains.

You might be able to write your own logic to test a single network or address against multiple networks efficiently, but that code would need to know about how IP addresses and network masks work. I'd suggest something based on a Trie, with special logic to support the host bits.

If you just want to write your looped code on a single line, you could use `any`:

```
if any(net2.network_address in key for key in dict1):
    ...
```

But that's not much nicer than your current code. It's also not exactly the same, since `any` short circuits after finding a single match. So the `any` code won't print multiple times if multiple keys contain `net2`'s address. You could replicate `any`'s behavior in your original looping code by putting a `break` after the `print` call in your code.